# ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: build, chocolatey, ninja

I installed chocolatey and then ninja using choco install ninja.
It got installed at 
`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ninja\tools`.

I added the path to the Environment variables too.
When I launch ninja now, it throws and error:

`ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.`

I just typed ninja on the powerShell prompt and this error is thrown! Does anyone have any idea of what's happening actually?

Comment: Same issue, tried ```choco install ninja``` and tried copying ninja.exe file directly (https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases), both added to the path.

Answer (score 10):

**The ninja build system on your computer worked correctly**. That error will occur if you run ninja with no arguments. If you add some arguments for it, such as `ninja --version` and it'll work as you expected

Answer (score 1):

i believe the build.ninja is generated when you run the meson command , so i believe something wrong with your build process

Comment: Thank you! That was it in my case, building Zathura.